# When using reusecab option WiX regenerates even cab files in output dirs for other solution configurations

Tags: wix

I have several solution configurations for my WiX solution and each solution config has a different set of files and different output dirs. Because I'm using -cc and -reusecab options and each solution config has different files, whenever I change solution config and build solution WiX regenerates cab files.

But the problem is that WiX regenerate not only the cab files for current(active) solution config but also the cab files for other solution configs in other output dirs. I'd like WiX not to regenerate cab files for other solution configs. Am I using WiX wrong way or is there a way to achieve my goal?

Thank you.